# how to display 404 page throgh config if custom module is disabled by custom admin

Tags: magento-1.9, 404-page

I am trying to show 404 error page whenever custom module has disabled by custome admin page .
In single page we put 404 error template  directly but more than one page if i want to show same 404 error page what i do

Comment: `$this->norouteAction();` should do the job.

Answer (score 2):

*Because my comment is the answer I post it again as answer so it can be accepted:*

You should use `$this->norouteAction();`.